# Solve an integral by bringing quadratic trinomial to canonical form

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The problem is the following:
$$\int{\sqrt{4x^2+x}dx}$$
Now once gotten to canonical form of a quadratic trinomial, $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-(\frac{-b}{2x}))^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$, the intregral looks like this:

$$\int{\sqrt{4(x+\frac{1}{8})^2-\frac{1}{16}}dx}=\int{\sqrt{(2x+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{1}{16}}dx}$$
With the substition of $2x+\frac{1}{4}=t$, $2dx=dt\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2}$ integral becomes:
$$\int{\sqrt{t^2-\frac{1}{16}}dx}$$
But what to do from here. I've seen a few solutions that involve a lot of trigonometry, but the book from which I got this problem states that the solution they got is:
$$\frac{2+x}{2}\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2ln|x+2+\sqrt{4x^2+x}|$$
How did they get to this exact solution?

Comment: At this point a standard solution is to make the trigonometric substitution $t = \frac{1}{4} \sec \theta$ or the hyperbolic substitution $t = \frac{1}{4} \cosh u$, both of which will eliminate the radical.

Comment: @TravisWillse but obviously those substitions won't give me the wanted solution. I'm mostly interested in the way how they got to this result.

Comment: Why is it "obvious" they won't get to that solution? To me, this seems entirely plausible and trig sub is the standard method for integrals of this type. Try performing the calculations and see what happens.

Comment: You can use Euler's substitution $\sqrt{4x^2+x}=2x+t$

Comment: @PrincessEev tried it didn't get the result in the wanted form

Comment: @Vasili the thing is Euler's supstition was mentioned only later on int the book, thus leading me to conclusion that it was probably not used

Comment: What is your book? I think its solution is false.

Comment: For a complete solution to your problem, which amounts to conquering $~\displaystyle \int \sqrt{(Cx + D)^2 - A^2} ~dx, ~$ see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658382/integrate-int-sqrtxaxb-space-dx/4658563#4658563).  See especially the equation labeled (2), in the cited answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval https://etfuni.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/zbirka-zadataka-iz-vise-matematike-1-ilicic-uscumlic.pdf problem 3356, page 269 and 585 for the solution

Comment: Re my last comment, I know that the solution on the line labeled (2) is correct.  So, the first thing that I would suggest that you do is compare my solution to the offered solution, and see if they differ **only by a constant**.  Two anti-derivatives that only differ by a constant are (in effect) equivalent.

Comment: @user2661923 the thing is that the book only later mentions trigonometric substitions, so highly unlikely they were used. But anyways I tried, but didn't get what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s=8x+1.$

$\int\sqrt{4x^2+x}\,dx=\frac1{32}\int\sqrt{s^2-1}\,ds$

Integrating by parts,

$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{s^2-1}\,ds&=[s\sqrt{s^2-1}]-\int\frac{s^2}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\,ds\\&=[s\sqrt{s^2-1}]-\int\frac{s^2-1}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\,ds-\int\frac1{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\,ds
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\int\sqrt{s^2-1}\,ds=\frac12\left([s\sqrt{s^2-1}]-\int\frac1{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\,ds\right).$$
Now (V p. 263 of [your book](https://etfuni.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/zbirka-zadataka-iz-vise-matematike-1-ilicic-uscumlic.pdf))
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{s^2-1}}\,ds=[\ln|s+\sqrt{s^2-1}|]$$
and we can conclude:
$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{4x^2+x}\,dx&=\frac1{64}[s\sqrt{s^2-1}-\ln|s+\sqrt{s^2-1}|]\\&=\frac1{64}[4(8x+1)\sqrt{4x^2+x}-\ln|8x+1+4\sqrt{4x^2+x}|]
\\&=\left[\frac{8x+1}{16}\sqrt{4x^2+x}-\frac1{64}\ln\left|\frac{8x+1}4+\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right|\right].
\end{align}$$
([WolframAlpha agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+%28%288x%2B1%29%5Csqrt%7B4x%5E2%2Bx%7D%2F16%29-+ln%7C%288x%2B1%29%2F4%2B%5Csqrt%7B4x%5E2%2Bx%7D%7C%2F64).)

(N.B. our notation "$[\dots]$" means "$\dots+$ constant", and in the two last expressions, the constants differ.)

This seems to be the intended method of your book but its solution is false, since it does not differ by a constant from this one.

Comment: Seems like the antiderivative given as result from the book is actually one from $\int{\sqrt{x^2+4x}dx}$, instead of the was given

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=x+a$, along with $a=\frac18$
$$I = \int \sqrt{4x^2+x}\ dx=2\int \sqrt{t^2-a^2}\ dt
$$

and integrate by parts
$$I = t \sqrt{t^2-a^2}
-a^2\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}
$$
To evaluate the remaining integral, let $s={\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}$ to get $sds=tdt$

$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}=\int \frac{d(t+s)}{t+s}=\ln|t+s|
$$

As a result
\begin{align}
I= t \sqrt{t^2-a^2}
-a^2\ln|t + \sqrt{t^2-a^2}|\\
\end{align}