# I need help with integrating an expression with multiple $x$ and $y$ terms

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The equation is $x^2+y^2 = 3\sqrt{2} x - 5\sqrt{2} y +2xy$. I need to try and find the area under the curve and above the x axis between $x = 0$ and $x = 3\sqrt{2}$. I've heard that implicit integration might help but after looking online I couldn't find much information if anyone knows how to do it or any resources that might help I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Get y as a function of x (2 solutions) and see where it is in the x range.  Integral looks straightforward.

Comment: See the second answer of Lanier Freeman.  It requires that you integrate an expression under the radical.  To do this, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658382/integrate-int-sqrtxaxb-space-dx/4658563#4658563).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this problem is to note that this is the parabola $y=-x^2+4x$ rotated $\pi/4$ rad clockwise.

[image: Original Graph]

[image: Rotated graph]

Thus, the area is given by the following:

$$A=\int_0^3-x^2+4x\;dx-\int_0^3x\;dx$$

$$\therefore A=\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is how to isolate $y$ to integrate explicitly.

Getting $y$ by itself on the LHS:

$$y^2+(5\sqrt2-x)y=-x^2+3\sqrt{2}x$$

Note $b=5\sqrt2-x$, so $b^2/4=\frac{50-10\sqrt2x+x^2}{4}$

$$\implies\left(y+\frac{5\sqrt2-x}{2}\right)^2=-x^2+3\sqrt2x+\frac{50-10\sqrt2x+x^2}{4}$$

$$\therefore y=\sqrt{-x^2+3\sqrt2x+\frac{50-10\sqrt2x+x^2}{4}}+\frac{x-5\sqrt2}{2}$$

I posted a better approach below--I'm leaving this up for now in case you find it useful/explanatory.